# How to check for skipped values in a series in a R dataframe column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `price1` in R that has four columns:

```
Name        Week         Price           Rebate
Car 1         1          20000            500
Car 1         2          20000            400
Car 1         5          20000            400
----          --          ----             ---
Car 1         54         20400            450
```

There are ten Car names in all in `price1`, so the above is just to give an idea about the structure. Each car name should have 54 observations corresponding to 54 weeks. But, there are some weeks for which no observation exists (for e.g., Week 3 and 4 in the above case). For these missing weeks, I need to plug in information from another dataframe `price2`:

```
Name        AveragePrice   AverageRebate
Car 1         20000            500
Car 2         20000            400
Car 3         20000            400
----          ----             ---
Car 10        20400            450
```

So, I need to identify the missing week for each Car name in `price1`, capture the row corresponding to that Car name in `price2`, and insert the row in `price1`. I just can't wrap my head around a possible approach, so unfortunately I do not have a code snippet to share. Most of my search in SO is leading me to answers regarding handling missing values, which is not what I am looking for. Can someone help me out?

I am also indicating the desired output below:

```
Name        Week         Price           Rebate
Car 1         1          20000            500
Car 1         2          20000            400
Car 1         3          20200            410
Car 1         4          20300            420
Car 1         5          20000            400
----          --          ----            ---
Car 1         54         20400            450
----          --          ----            ---
Car 10        54         21400            600
```

Note that the output now has Car 1 info for Week 4 and 5 which I should fetch from `price2`. Final output should contain 54 observations for each of the 10 car names, so total of 540 rows.

Comment: Would it be possible to show us what your desired final goal looks like? (aka: expected results)

Comment: I edited my question to include the desired output. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Where is the Car 1 week 3, and Car 1 week 4 information coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, good luck

```
library(data.table)
carNames <- paste('Car', 1:10)
df <- data.table(Name = rep(carNames, each = 54), Week = rep(1:54, times = 10))
df <- merge(df, price1, by = c('Name', 'Week'), all.x = TRUE)
df <- merge(df, price2, by = 'Name', all.x = TRUE); df[, `:=`(Price = ifelse(is.na(Price), AveragePrice, Price), Rebate = ifelse(is.na(Rebate), AverageRebate, Rebate))] 
df[, 1:4]
```

Comment: This works! Thanks a ton incas56! I didn't quite get the fifth line of the code though. What does the operator ``:=`` do?

Comment: `:=` from package `data.table`,  fast add, remove and update subsets of columns, by `reference`.https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.10.4-2/topics/%3A%3D

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your problem correctly you basically have 2 dataframes and you want to make sure the dataframe - "price1" has the correct rownames(names of the cars) in the 'names' column?

Here's what I would do, but it probably isn't the optimal way:

```
#create a loop with length = number of rows in your frame
for(i in 1:nrow(price1)){
  #check if the value is = NA,
  if (is.na(price1[1,i] == TRUE){
    #if it is NA, replace it with the corresponding value in price2
    price1[1,i] <- price2[1,i]
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps (:

Comment: isn't this checking for NA values? When I say a week is missing, I mean there is no row corresponding to that week in `price1`. I feel I should be capturing the missing week for a car name, say Car 1, and then fetch the appropriate row from `price2`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you only want to see what is in the 2nd table and not in the first. You will just want to use an `anti_join`. Note that the order you feed the tables into the `anti_join` matters.

```
library(tidyverse)
complete_table ->
    price2 %>%
    anti_join(price1)
```

To expand your first table to cover all 54 weeks use `complete()` or you can even fudge it and `right_join` a table that you will purposely build with all 54 weeks in it. Then anything that doesn't join to this second table gets an `NA` in that column.

Comment: No, this doesn't work for me. Sorry, maybe I am not clear enough in my explanation. I need to look at `price1` and see which `Week` is missing for each car name. Since I have 10 car names, I should have 10*54 weeks = 540 rows in `price1`. But, now I have only 516. So, I need to fill the missing 24 rows in `price1` using data from `price2`. I hope this clarifies.